# SQL get values of all rows in a table that share the same values of one column

Tags: sql

I have a column called "index" that is associated with the values that I need to extract depending its value. For example, in the table below I would only want to select the information in the company,disease1,disease2, and disease3 columns if they all shared the same value in the index column. How would I create a query that does this?

| company | disease1 | disease2 | disease3 | index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| text | num | num | num | 1 |
| text | num | num | num | 2 |
| text | num | num | num | 1 |
| text | num | num | num | 1 |
| text | num | num | num | 3 |
| text | num | num | num | 3 |

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you familiar with DISTINCT or GROUP BY syntax?

Comment: Your description is unclear to me. Please **edit** the question and show is what result you expect, given some example data.

Comment: You will have to add more detail. What do you mean "if they all share" - so are you looking for a specific `index` value - in which case that's just a simple `where` criteria? Or do you want rows that have at least one index value in common, ie all rows except index=2, or something else entirely?

Comment: @lillup do you have a single table, or are you trying to join multiple tables of data?  Can you provide more information about the tables (table names) and an example of the the output?